# Javascript this.superclass.constructor() and extend()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extend, superclass

These codes were extracted from the example for abstract decorator in the book of "[Learning Javascript Design Patterns](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#decoratorpatternjavascript)". I got confused by `this.superclass.constructor()` and `extend()`.

I can understand `this` refers to `myMacbookPro`, an instance of `CaseDecorator` here. But what does `this.superclass` refer? Why not just `this.constructor(macbook)`?

`CaseDecorator`'s superclass is `MacbookDecorator`? Where did the inheritance happen? 
Are they part of native Javascript or an 3rd party library?

Thanks

```
var CaseDecorator = function(macbook) {
    // call the superclass's constructor next
    this.superclass.constructor(macbook);
};

// Let's now extend the superclass
extend(CaseDecorator, MacbookDecorator); 
....
// Decorate the macbook
myMacbookPro = new CaseDecorator(myMacbookPro);
```

Comment: `this.superclass.constructor()` is taking the property `superclass` of `this`, getting its constructor, and calling it. None of it is built into JavaScript. Bit of an icky pattern, this.

Comment: minitech, I understood what you said in general. But I got lost with the concrete objects in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's construct the extend function and change the way the superclass is called:

```
function extend(subClass, superClass) {
    var F = function() {}
    F.prototype = superClass.prototype
    subClass.prototype = new F()
    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass
    subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype
    if(superClass.prototype.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor){
        superClass.prototype.constructor = superClass
    }
}
```

The superclass calling method:

```
CaseDecorator.superclass.constructor.call(this, macbook)
```

Answer (score -1):

Extend takes two objects, and combines them.  If you have two properties that are the same, but a third property in one of the objects, the final object has three properties. Example:

```
var object1 = { name: "Test1", sex: "male" };
var object 2 = { job: "Worker" }

var extendedObject = $.extend(object1, object2);
```

The extended object will be:

```
objectExtended = { name: "Test", sex: "male", job: "Worker" }
```

Comment: That appears to be jQuery. The question’s `extend` does not appear to be jQuery.